# How to make clipboard.js to copy text to clipboard without pressing any button

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

As far as I know clipboard.js copies text only when button or link is clicked. Is there other way to copy text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clipboard.js creator here.

Due to security restrictions imposed by browser vendors, user interaction is required in order copy/cut to work. A simulated click event using JavaScript does not work as this would enable clipboard poisoning.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation